# How to check if collection exists in supabase with python?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

Given a client connection to supabase, how can I check if a collection exists with the variable symbol before creating it? Reason is I don't want to re-create the collections every run. Can't find anything on supabase-py documentation:

```
Client = supabase_py.create_client(url, key)

CONNECTION_STRING = PGVector.connection_string_from_db_params(
    driver=os.environ.get("PGVECTOR_DRIVER", "psycopg2"),
    host=os.environ.get("PGVECTOR_HOST", "db.xxxxxx.supabase.co"),
    port=int(os.environ.get("PGVECTOR_PORT", "XXXX")),
    database=os.environ.get("PGVECTOR_DATABASE", "postgres"),
    user=os.environ.get("PGVECTOR_USER", "postgres"),
    password=os.environ.get("PGVECTOR_PASSWORD", "XXXXXXX"),
)

db = PGVector.from_documents(
            embedding=embeddings,
            documents=texts_to_embed,
            collection_name=symbol,
            connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING,
        )
```

Comment: If you are referring to rows when you say collections, you can query the table before you insert using the `select()` method along with the `eq` filter. https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/eq

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.get_by_name()](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/5d8a689d5e5d9d087f543c83d0ff0edc87d476d8/libs/langchain/langchain/vectorstores/_pgvector_data_models.py#L26) method from the CollectionStore to check it. If it returns None it doesn't exist yet, other wise it exists.

Check a print from the [LLangchain github](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/5d8a689d5e5d9d087f543c83d0ff0edc87d476d8/libs/langchain/langchain/vectorstores/_pgvector_data_models.py#L26) using it.

[image]

Your code would look something like this:

```
collection_name = "your_collection_name"
pgvector = PGVector(
embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings(), 
collection_name=collection_name, 
connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING
)
with Session(pgvector._conn) as session:
    collection = pgvector.CollectionStore.get_by_name(session, collection_name)
if collection:
    print("It exists!!")
else:
    print("It doesn't exists.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **get_or_create_collection**.

```
DB_CONNECTION = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:54322/postgres"

# create vector store client
vx = vecs.create_client(DB_CONNECTION)

# get or create a collection of vectors with 1408 dimensions
vec = vx.get_or_create_collection(name="image_vectors", dimension=1408)
```